# How to resize a UITableView for custom dynamic expanding UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm using a custom UITableViewCell I've created to expand a cell when it's touched. I do this using beginUpdates/endUpdates, which in turn call heightForRowAtIndexPath. It works fine, the cell expands, the label I have on it displays. All good so far.

The only issue is the UITableView itself isn't resizing to account for the extra height of the cell.

I've read about resizing the frame, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can do this, because it feels like it should be pretty simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, I believe I ran into the same problem recently.  I found the answer in a macheads 101 tutorial on youtube.  His example dealt with a UITableView that resized itself to account for a keyboard display.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:
    @selector(keyBoardHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

this is in the viewDidLoad method and it calls keyBoardHidden which looks like this:

```
- (void)keyBoardHidden:(NSNotification *)note {
    //[[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0].textLabel setText:@""];
    //[tableView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    CGRect searchBarFrame = searchBar.frame;
    CGRect newTableViewFrame = CGRectMake (0, (float)searchBarFrame.size.height,
        320, 480);
    [tableView setFrame:newTableViewFrame];     
}
```

He resized the frame with the simple command [tableView setFrame:self.view.bounds]; but that left the top cell hidden by the search bar, which I originally solved by just blanking out the first cell, but I then decided that was bush league and told the UITableView frame to start at the bottom of the search bar.  I left the other solution in comments though in case it is useful to you.

Unfortunately this is only an example.  I am not knowledgable enough to be able to tell you where to implement these techniques in your code.  I hope that this is somehow useful anyway.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thanks Sam. It hasn't fixed it, but it's certainly got me closer! I'll come back with my final solution when I find it. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help you some. Interestingly enough, I am working on a more complex version of the same idea and I am now running into that problem too.  Everything else works, but the table view no longer resizes properly.  The same code that worked before is now failing.  I am also searching it out, and it will be interesting to see if one of us can find a solution that we can use to solve it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9610454/1227207) This is a link to a question I asked about essentially the same problem just so we can have two lines in the water.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but I would say you shouldn't be resizing the table view size, its a scroll view so you should be adjusting the contentSize property

Comment: Nope, he should be changing the frame. The tableview itself will take care of the contentSize thanks to heightForRowAtIndexPath. Without seeing code though it's hard to say why it isn't working.

Comment: sorry I read that as he is trying to resize the frame of the tableview, which I don't believe should be done

Comment: Ok, so, I can't work out how to put a block of code in a comment. Sorry. My `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method returns 44, or 200 if the row is the selected row - this is set using a variable in the `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`. It seems pretty simple to me... which is why I suspect I don't understand properly.